# Which Veda Shaka, Gotra etc, will a person should follow after he was converted into Brahmin, Kshatriya or Vaishya?

Tags: caste-system, dharma-shastras

All Smritis are clear that Varna is primarily based on birth. A person born as a Brahmin will lose his status if his conduct is not good, but even if a person born as a Shudra has good conduct, he cannot become a Brahmin. And all Smritis provide eligible ages for Upanayana Samskara only for first three Varnas. But, there are some verses in the Ithihasa and Puranas, which seems to be saying a low born person can attain higher caste.

For example, [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16417/can-a-sudra-become-a-brahmin-in-this-birth/16418#16418) says it is possible to attain higher Varna through five syllables mantra [This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30157/can-a-sudra-attain-higher-caste-according-to-manusmriti/33255#33255) quotes verses from Brahma Purana chapter 115 and says it is possible to attain higher castes through good conduct.

> [Mahabharata Shanti Parva Chapter 189](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b016.htm):
>
> **That person is called a Brahmana who has been sanctified by such rites as those called jata and others; who is pure in behaviour; who
>   is engaged in studying the Vedas; who is devoted to the six well-known
>   acts (of ablutions every morning and evening, silent recitation of
>   mantras, pouring libations on the sacrificial fire, worshipping the
>   deities, doing the duties of hospitality to guests, and offering food
>   to the Viswedevas); who is properly observant of all pious acts; who
>   never takes food without having offered it duly to gods and guests;
>   who is filled with reverence for his preceptor; and who is always
>   devoted to vows and truth. He is called a Brahmana in whom are truth,
>   gifts, abstention from injury to others, compassion, shame,
>   benevolence, and penance.** He who is engaged in the profession of
>   battle, who studies the Vedas, who makes gifts (to Brahmanas) and
>   takes wealth (from those he protects) is called a Kshatriya. He who
>   earns fame from keep of cattle, who is employed in agriculture and the
>   means of acquiring wealth, who is pure in behaviour and attends to the
>   study of the Vedas, is called a Vaisya. **He who takes pleasure in
>   eating every kind of food, who is engaged in doing every kind of work,
>   who is impure in behaviour, who does not study the Vedas, and whose
>   conduct is unclean, is said to be a Sudra**. **If these
>   characteristics be observable in a Sudra, and if they be not found in
>   a Brahmana, then such a Sudra is no Sudra, and, such a Brahmana is no
>   Brahmana.**

Now, my question is, If a person from the lowest varna attains any other upper varna through good conduct or any other way mentioned above, which Veda Shaka, Gotra, Pravara, Sutra does such a person will acquire?

Comment: Related [According to guṇa-based varṇa system, at what age can one be certified a brāhmaṇa, kṣatriya, etc?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26841/3500)